# Comparing to methods / models with human evaluators

Tags: experiment-design

I have 2 methods / models. I want to compare them using expert human raters so the amount of samples/tests must be small.

I want to figure out which is the better method.

What is a good way of doing this?
Compare directly 1:1? Or just let them rate everything in random order and then see which method wins more often? How do I then determine statistical significance?

Answer (score 0):

Do a group Test of Difference but Repeated Measure design (ANOVA, Friedman, etc) and in your following post-hoc analysis (if previous test was significant), it's a many-to-one where all are paired to the "expert".